# Strange issue with str function versus Str

Tags: vba, excel

I have one of the stranges problems I have encountered for many years.  I have a Workbook with a lot of code that validates the users data and has been used for many years now. A user reported that the latest version of the file was crashing excel and giving him an "automation error".  To my knowledge the changes made to the most recent file were minor and should not have caused this.  On analysis the cause of the problem was straight forward, but how it happened, why it happened and how to fix it, I do not know.
The issue occurred due to the below line of code, which is expecting a numeric, but the user supplied a string:

```
Ltrim(Str(Usersdata(UsersDataRow,UUID_Col)))
```

Note the upper case S on str.  The previous version of the workbook has the same line but str is in all lower case, and does NOT crash excel.
Both files syntax check perfectly.  But the strangest thing is when I have both old and new version of the file open in the VBA editor.
If I edit the line in the old file and change str to Str, the editor autocorrects it back to all lower case str. 
If I edit the new workbook and change Str to str, the editor autocorrects it back to init cap Str.
So as it stands, I cannot correct the new file.
This behaviour is very strange and am hoping someone can tell me how it has happened and possibly how to solve it?

Comment: `Str` is correct. You are getting `str` because most probably you have declared a variable with that name somewhere in your code. And hence one should avoid using reserved names as variables. There is also a possibility that you have a procedure with that name. Do a search in your VBA project for `str`

Comment: Siddharth Rout - Accept that Str is correct, but I don't have str as a variable and if I did, Ltrim(str(Usersdata(UsersDataRow,UUID_Col))) would not compile surely?  (Which it does, and has worked for over 5 years)

Comment: Compiling is not a problem. `Dim str(1) As String: str(0) = "sid": Debug.Print str(0)` will also compile but it is not the same as `Debug.Print Str(0)` ;) May I see your file?

Comment: I am afraid I am not allowed to share the file for commercial copyright reasons, but as well as that it is over 10,000 lines of vba code.  In the editor if I delete the word str and then retype it, autocomplete will show me  the (num) tooltip, telling me it is the string function and expects a number.  Doing the same thing in the other file does exactly the same but shows Str ... very very confused :(

Comment: You are missing the point. The code that I gave `Dim str(1) As String: str(0) = "sid": Debug.Print str(0)` .Here if you type `Debug.Print str(` It will give the numeric prompt... But it is not the same. I recommend pressing CTRL H in your VBA editor and search for `str`

Comment: BTW what is the error that you are getting? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I already did that and as I said, there are no variables, procedures or functions called str.  I get "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" followed by "Microsoft Excel is trying to recover your information", and then eventually "automation error".  I discovered the offending line by stepping through the code.  Commenting the above line out and the file works fine, so its definitely that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89014/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mark-moore).

Comment: I do understand your point, my confusion is caused by the fact there is no other object called str, coupled with the fact that changes from the previous version to this one have not been massive and the no changes at all in the procedure thats now crashing.  I feel it must be environmental in some way, but no idea what

Comment: Just a thought, but I'm pretty sure that all projects loaded will effect the variable names. So you could have a name conflict with code in a VBA add-in or a Personal workbook, even if hidden.

Comment: You don't have to still have a variable called `str` - if you did at any point in that workbook, you'll see that behaviour. Just add `Dim Str`, compile, then delete the declaration and you should see `str` automatically correct to `Str` thereafter. Note: VBA is not case sensitive in this way, so this is probably all moot. :)

Comment: @Rory: Yes it can be moot but I have a feeling it is not... (i could be wrong) If you have the time just have a look at the comments in the chat window.. Maybe I missed something? Always better to have things looked at with fresh pair of eyes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding fixing the main problem I suggest replacing the line

`Ltrim(Str(Usersdata(UsersDataRow,UUID_Col)))`

with a more thorough input validation that can handle alphanumeric values

---

.

As Siddharth Rout suggested in the comments:

The symptoms you describe indicate that the **VBA name space has been corrupted**

The most common source are variable names like "**str**", "**val**", "**name**", "**file**", "**count**", "**cell**", "**row**" etc

A quick way to check name conflicts is to click inside the variable name and press <kbd>F1</kbd>;

- the Help should show "*Keyword Not Found*"

---

.

The experiment bellow can demonstrate the problem: open a new Excel, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for VBA

1. paste this code in a standard module:

---

```
Sub test1()

    Dim txt As String   'valid variable name

    txt = Str("123")    'Str() remains with a capital S

End Sub
```

---

.

2. Now replace the code with this (obvious problem):

---

```
Sub test2()

    Dim str As String   'invalid variable name

    str = str("123")    'Str() is converted to lower case "s"

End Sub
```

---

.

VBA is now corrupted and here is one way to fix it:

- close the file
- reopen it, and do not allow macros to run
- open VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)
- perform a **Search and Replace** in **all VBA modules** for "str" (replace "str" with "Str")

  - Match Case
  - <s>Find Whole Word Only</s>
  - **Current Project** <-- most important setting

The Replace operation will be performed only once, because VBA will automatically convert all other instances of "str" to "Str" before any other replacements

Name space is now restored the next time you open the file

(the procedure forces a recompilation of the P-code generated for all modules)

Another way to re-generate clean P-code is to export each individual standard module as *.bas files, *.cls for Class modules, and *.frm for user forms code, and import all into a new Excel file

Comment: `Val(Usersdata(UsersDataRow,UUID_Col))` That is a wrong suggestion. Please read the comments in the chat window. the problem is that the user was adding "a" before every number and hence the error. Op is now planning to put validation when the user enters something. `?val("a123")` will give you `0` which OP wouldn't want :)

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout. I updated the answer with more relevant info

Comment: Thanks Paul Bica, Siddharth Rout - I was aware before posting I needed to add a validation to the offending column to ensure it was numeric (amazed it wasn't there already considering the other extensive validation) my question was about the other strange behaviour.  You have all helped with my understanding, and I exported all the code, reimported it into a brand new workbook, copied all the sheets from the old work book, copied my ribbon code and now have a fresh version of the workbook and the problem has gone away.  So clean code was the answer.  Thanks all